# Pausar execução usando SweetAlert (swal, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, front-end, sweetalert

Olá,
Basicamente eu tenho um while em JavaScript rodando, dependendo do resultado ele me apresenta uma mensagem informativa, eu quero exibir essa mensagem informativa e continuar a execução após o usuário clicar em "OK".

Atualmente eu estou usando o alert do JavaScript, pois ele prossegue o código apenas quando o usuário clica no botão.

```
alert("Usuário sem info cadastrada");
```

Eu desejo usar a biblioteca SweetAlert, pois ela cria alertas mais amigáveis, estou criando um alerta da seguinte maneira.

```
swal("Ops!", "Usuário sem info cadastrada", "error");
```

O problema é que o while continua executando, sem esperar o usuário clicar no botão OK, um alerta substitui o outro. Eu preciso que o while continue apenas se o usuário clicar no botão, para que o usuário possa visualizar todos os problemas que estão ocorrendo.

Answer (score 1):

Para pausar um `while`, você pode usar [promises](/questions/tagged/promises). Como o *framework* [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) trabalha com isto, então basta usar o operador *await*.

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.querySelector('button')
  /**
   * Utiliza o operador `async` para informar que é
   * uma função assíncrona (Obrigatório)
   */
  .addEventListener('click', async ev => {
    
    /* Inicia o contador */
    let i = 0
    console.group('While')

    while (i < 10) {
      console.log( i )

      if (i % 2) {
        /**
         * Utiliza o operador `await` para informar
         * ao JavaScript que é para esperar o resultado
         * da função antes de prosseguir
         */
        await Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer')
      }
      
      i++
    }
    
    console.groupEnd()
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<!--
Polyfill para IE11
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>
-->

<button type="button">Start</button>
```

Complementos:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/280445/99718
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273010/99718